# The "landscape" description for fixing the Android app screen in landscape orientation is not recognized

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am developing an android app.
The languages are HTML5 and cordova.
I added the following code to manifest.json as reference.

However, the screen of the built application is not fixed horizontally.
The screen will not turn sideways unless the smartphone with the app is turned sideways.
I want to keep the screen sideways even when the smartphone is facing vertically.
What's wrong with my code?
I've looked through the past logs and couldn't find a clear answer

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "short_name": ""example",",
  "description": ""example",",
  "display":      "standalone", 
  "orientation":  "landscape",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/icons/icon-48x48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  },more....
```

The same screen as when the Android smartphone is in landscape orientation is required to be maintained when the device is in portrait orientation.

Currently, when the smartphone is in portrait orientation, the landscape screen cannot be maintained, and the screen configuration has changed to portrait orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I found and resolved best practices.
This is not use manifest.json.
What I really wanted to do here was to have the config.xml point to the landscape view.

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="com.example.foovar" version="1.3.0" android-versionCode="130">
<preference name="Example" value="false"/>
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>
</widget>
```